# Seq API: Authenticating using Integrated Security?

Tags: c#, powershell, serilog, getseq, seq-logging

Without authentication enabled on my Seq instance, I'm perfectly able to work with it from powershell, that is, the following just works:

`Invoke-RestMethod "https://myseqinstance/api/dashboards?shared"`

However, now that I've enabled Active Directory authentication and added a login for myself, I can still access the Seq UI, but calling the API fails.

`Invoke-RestMethod "https://myseqinstance/api/dashboards?shared" -UseDefaultCredentials`

This now produces an HTTP 401 - Unauthorized error.

I figured that I might need to login, so I've tried a HTTP GET and POST of the following

```
# Produces HTTP 403
Invoke-RestMethod "https://myseqinstance/api/users/login" -UseDefaultCredentials
# Produces HTTP 400
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post "https://myseqinstance/api/users/login" -UseDefaultCredentials
```

So neither works, even though integrated security should be possible...
How can I authenticate against the Seq API using integrated security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here is to use an API key - you can do this in the Seq UI by clicking on your username and selecting "API keys".

On the command-line, the API key token can be passed in a header:

```
$headers = @{
    'X-Seq-ApiKey' = '<token>'
}
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://myseqinstance/api/dashboards?shared" -Method Get -Headers $headers
```

Its usually much more convenient to use the [`seqcli` command-line client](https://github.com/datalust/seqcli), if the commands you need are in there. If not, [*Seq.Api*](https://github.com/datalust/seq-api) (a client library in C#) covers the complete API and makes a lot of automation tasks easier.